# swipe directive in ionic framework?

Tags: touch, ionic-framework

Does ionic has directives for swiping or other events?
I found this service: `$ionicGesture`. Should I make my own directives with this?

Or should I use something else like ngTouch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any swipe directives right out of the box, but since the events are exposed, it's pretty simple to throw something together.

```
.directive('detectGestures', function($ionicGesture) {
  return {
    restrict :  'A',

    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var gestureType = attrs.gestureType;

      switch(gestureType) {
        case 'swipe':
          $ionicGesture.on('swipe', scope.reportEvent, elem);
          break;
        case 'swiperight':
          $ionicGesture.on('swiperight', scope.reportEvent, elem);
          break;
        case 'swipeleft':
          $ionicGesture.on('swipeleft', scope.reportEvent, elem);
          break;
        case 'doubletap':
          $ionicGesture.on('doubletap', scope.reportEvent, elem);
          break;
        case 'tap':
          $ionicGesture.on('tap', scope.reportEvent, elem);
          break;
      }

    }
  }
})
```

[Check out this demo](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/EImgd)

Comment: Thanks. I also did something like this. It could be made more general like this: <div swipe-left='someFunction()>

Comment: Nothing like that exists yet, but making the gesture api more accessible is on the rode map

Answer (score 10):

Seems like the swipe directives didn't exist when this question was active, but they are available now: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onSwipe/

```
<button on-swipe="onSwipe()" class="button">Test</button>
```

Also avaiable: `on-swipe-left`, `on-swipe-right`, `on-swipe-up` and `on-swipe-down`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial explaining how to do that with Ionicframework and AngularJS
http://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-swipeable-cards/

Basically you gonna create a View using the Ionicframework objetcs/functions
like the snippet bellow, and create a directive that will call it. See details in the tutorial.

```
var SwipeableCardView = ionic.views.View.inherit({   
    initialize: function(opts) {
    // Store the card element
    this.el = opts.el;
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {

    var self = this;

    ionic.onGesture('drag', function(e) {
       // Process drag
    }, this.el);

    ionic.onGesture('dragend', function(e) {
       // Process end of drag
    }, this.el);
},
```